# Reverse Loop ignores some cells

Tags: vba, loops

I have written a small code that allow me to:
in a defined range (xrng) in column F, find all the cells that contain certain text and once found, select all the cells in the range A:G on the same row and delete them. I have a reverse loop, which work partially, as ignores some cells in the range, specifically the 2nd and the 3rd. Below a before and after pic:

[image]

Here my code:

```
  Sub removeapp()

    Dim g As Long, xrng As Range, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    i = 4
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set xrng = Range(Cells(lastrow, "F"), Cells(i, "F"))

        For g = xrng.Count To i Step -1

            If xrng.Cells(g).Value = "Adjustment" Or xrng.Cells(g).Value = "Approved" Then
            Range(Cells(xrng.Cells(g).Row(), "A"), Cells(xrng.Cells(g).Row(), "G")).Delete
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Could you help me to figure out why? 
Also, the code runs really slow... if you have any tip to make it slighlty faster would be great!

Comment: Your loop stops at row 4.

Comment: @SJR yes, the picture is now updated. the first line is actually on row 4.

Comment: Your loop should run to 1 as otherwise you are still stopping at the 4th cell of `xrng` - your reference is relative `xrng.Cells(g)`.

Comment: Oooh! Clear :) it works. Do you see any way that the code could run faster? Anyway thanks!

Comment: There's plenty around on this. Using autofilter would be much quicker than looping.

Comment: okay! I will have a look, thanks!

Comment: don't forget to turn off screen updating and setting the calculations to manual at the start of the routine and then back on at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please:

```
Sub removeappOrig()
    Dim xrng As Range, lastrow As Long, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'good to put here your real sheet
    lastrow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Set xrng = sh.Range("A4:F" & lastrow)
    xrng.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="=Adjustment", Operator:=xlOr, _ 
                            Criteria2:="=Approved", VisibleDropDown:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru kind of. it removes what I want to keep, and leave the remaining rows hidden. also it deletes the entire row, which is not okay for me, as next to that table there will be other data.

Comment: Sorry... I'l fix it in a moment. Please refresh the page and try it. In principle you just have to replace `"<>"` with `"="` and `xlAnd` with `xlOr`... I didn't have a similar table to test it and I was too lazy to prepare one :-)

Comment: It is better, but still it removes the entire row, and leave the remaining ones hidden.

Comment: I updated the answer in a way to turn the filter off. Refresh the page, please. But, reading "select all the cells in the range A:G on the same row and delete them" and nothing else to the table right side, this made me think that this faster solution would be good.. Do you have some other filled columns after H:H, column, or you only want a solution answering your question exactly? I could see only two words clarifying something...

Comment: I do have other data after H:H, this is why my loop was going only through A:G and removing those. So, if I had to remove the entire column, your solution would be good. But it is not my specific case... does it make it clearer?

Comment: Now, i's clear. Unfortunately, when a filter is applied you cannot delete ranges (programmatically or manually) except EntireRow... I will post a code which will work. Not as fast as AutoFilter, but fast enough, I hope...

Comment: @G_TTI: I updated the code in order to be extremely fast. Please test it and let me know if it does what you need with adequate speed.

Answer (score 0):

The next code is also fast enough since it iterates between array elements (in memory), not deletes row by row (it creates a ranges Union) and delete all at once:

```
Private Sub remoRangesAtOnce()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, sh As Worksheet
    Dim arrF As Variant, rng As Range, rngDel As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'please name it according to your sheet name
    lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = sh.Range("F4:F" & lastRow)

    arrF = rng.Value
     For i = LBound(arrF) To UBound(arrF)
        If arrF(i, 1) = "Adjustment" Or arrF(i, 1) = "Approved" Then
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & i + 3), sh.Range("F" & i + 3))
            Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & i + 3), sh.Range("F" & i + 3)))
            End If
        End If
     Next i
     If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete xlShiftUp
End Sub
```